# Is it possible to insert a line of no discrimination in ROC plot using ggroc?

Tags: r, plot, roc, proc-r-package

I have created a ROC plot with multiple ROC-curves using ggroc based on pROC. How can I insert a line of no discrimination?

I would like to have a line of no discrimination from 0,0 to 1,1 in my plot, so that I can better visually evaluate my ROC-curves.

I have tried using the plot() function on my ggplot object, and I have tried using + geom_abline(), and the lines() function without any luck.

```
library(pROC)

#Creating curves and labeling)
ROC_curves <- ggroc(list(log=ROC_log, tree=ROC_tree, xgbt=ROC_xgbt), legacy.axes=TRUE)

ROC_curves2 <- ROC_curves + xlab("FPR") + ylab("TPR")
#but this part doesn't Work: 
+ qplot(1,1) + geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1)
```

I have also tried doing:
     plot(ROC_curves2, identity=TRUE)

I would like a line of no discrimination going from 0,0 to 1,1 in my plot.

When adding qplot(1,1) + geom_abline(), I get "Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot".
When using plot() a plot is returned, but still with no line.

Comment: The intercept should be equal to 1 (in your geom_abline)

Comment: Also, the error is due to adding qplot(1,1) (a new qqplot) to an existing ggplot. You need to remove this part of your command.

Comment: The intercept should be 0, but it worked, with deleting qplot()!

Answer (score 3):

The `ROC_curves` already returns a ggplot plot. Adding a new plot to it with `qplot` is not possible nor necessary, just add `geom_abline` directly:

```
ROC_curves + xlab("FPR") + ylab("TPR") + 
    geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1,
                color = "darkgrey", linetype = "dashed")
```

The abline extends beyond the limits of the ROC curve. To avoid that you can use `geom_segment` instead:

```
ROC_curves + xlab("FPR") + ylab("TPR") + 
    geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 1, y = 0, yend = 1),
                 color="darkgrey", linetype="dashed")
```

Also note that if you weren't using `legacy.axes=TRUE` you would need to have `intercept = 1` so that the line crosses the 0 line on the top right.

```
... + geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 1, y = 0, yend = 1)) # legacy.axes = TRUE
... + geom_segment(aes(x = 1, xend = 0, y = 0, yend = 1)) # legacy.axes = FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

@Calimo's solution didn't work for me but I think that is due to the size of my dataset so the graph won't render. Found a gitlab issue (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4190) about how `annotate` is much faster than `geom_segment`. I'm using the following:

`+  annotate("segment",x = 1, xend = 0, y = 0, yend = 1, color="red", linetype="dashed")`